# Collision detection using pure jQuery is not giving desired output

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, collision-detection

I am **trying** to develop a very simple game where the **ship (red box)** will move left-right when user clicks on playground.

There are some moving **walls (black boxes)** as obstacles that the ship should avoid colliding with.

If any collision happens, the walls will stop moving and a text will be printed out in console.

I have succeeded to get this as close as I can. **But its working sometime, not always**. You can see it in the code below, try to collide with wall. Sometime it will stop them and print text, sometime it will just ignore the collision as if nothing happens.

I have no clue why this is happening.

Here is the code.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {

  var $totalHeight = $('.inner').height(); //of walls
  var $maxHeight = Math.ceil(Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) - (Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) * 30) / 100); //30% of total wall height

  $('.wall').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).height($maxHeight);
    $('.wall.four').css({
      'height': $wallGap
    });
  })

  var $wallGap = Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) - $maxHeight;
  var $wallOneTop = 0;
  var $wallTwoTop = $maxHeight + $wallGap;
  var $wallThreeTop = ($maxHeight * 2) + ($wallGap * 2);
  var $wallFourTop = -$('.wall.four').height() - $wallGap;

  $('.wall.one').css({
    'top': $wallOneTop
  });
  $('.wall.two').css({
    'top': $wallTwoTop
  });
  $('.wall.three').css({
    'top': $wallThreeTop
  });
  $('.wall.four').css({
    'top': $wallFourTop
  });


  function moveWall(wallObj) {
    var $currentTop = wallObj.position().top;
    var $limitTop = $('.inner').height();

    if ($currentTop >= $limitTop) {
      var $rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($maxHeight - $wallGap + 1) + $wallGap);
      wallObj.height($rand);
      var $top = -(wallObj.height());
    } else {
      var $top = (wallObj.position().top) + 5;
    }
    var $collide = checkCollision(wallObj);
    wallObj.css({
      'top': $top
    });
    return $collide;
  }

  var $wallTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $('.wall').each(function(i, obj) {
      var $status = moveWall($(this));
      if ($status == true) {
        clearInterval($wallTimer);
      }
    })
  }, 40);


  function checkCollision(wallObj) {
    var $ship = $('.ship');
    var $shipWidth = $ship.width();
    var $shipHeight = $ship.height();
    var $shipLeft = $ship.position().left;
    var $shipRight = $shipLeft + $shipWidth;
    var $shipTop = $ship.position().top;
    var $shipBottom = $shipTop + $shipHeight;

    var $wall = wallObj;
    var $wallWidth = wallObj.width();
    var $wallHeight = wallObj.height();
    var $wallLeft = wallObj.position().left;
    var $wallRight = $wallLeft + $wallWidth;
    var $wallTop = wallObj.position().top;
    var $wallBottom = $wallTop + $wallHeight;

    if (
      $shipLeft >= $wallRight ||
      $shipRight <= $wallLeft ||
      $shipTop >= $wallBottom ||
      $shipBottom <= $wallTop
    ) {
      return false;
    } else {
      console.log("dhumm!");
      return true;
    }
  }







  $('.outer .inner').click(function() {
    var $ship;
    $ship = $('.ship');
    $shipLeft = $ship.position().left;
    $shipRight = $shipLeft + $ship.width();

    $inner = $('.inner');
    $innerLeft = $inner.position().left;
    $innerRight = $innerLeft + $inner.width();


    if (($shipLeft < $inner.width() - $ship.width())) {
      $ship.animate({
        "left": $inner.width() - $ship.width()
      }, 500, "linear");
    } else if (($shipRight >= $inner.width())) {
      $ship.animate({
        "left": '0'
      }, 500, "linear");
    }

  });


});
```

```css
.outer {
  background: #fff;
  border: 20px solid #efefef;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer .inner {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer .inner .wall {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #000;
}

.outer .inner .ship {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="wall one"></div>
    <div class="wall two"></div>
    <div class="wall three"></div>
    <div class="wall four"></div>

    <div class="ship"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: At a guess I would say it's because you're only checking for collision when the wall is moving, not when the ship is moving.  Changing the setTimeout from 40 to 500 and you hardly ever get a collision as the ship goes through the wall.  Equally, changing the ship animation time so it takes longer and you hardly every get a false-negative

Comment: Oh ok.. understood. But how can I check for the moving position of ship? I mean the walls are moving by a function +5 pixels from the top and each time it moves, **checkCollision()** is called. But with *ship* element, it moves directly to right (or left) with a single click. **How to check the position of the ship when it is moving?**

Comment: Possibly use the same process to move the ship as you do the wall?  ie setTimeout with steps and checks.  You could include it in the moveWall function so everything moves together (40ms is 25fps so would appear smooth).  You could then improve efficiency by storing the position of the ship as `.position()` is probably the slowest part of your code.

Comment: @freedomn-m Alright, thanks for the explanation. I'll try that, and will give update if I can make that work. Thanks a lot. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As freefomn-m already said.
Check for collision in the animation cycle of the ship, not the walls.

For this I use the second type of parameters for jQuery's `.animate` method

[`.animate( properties, options )`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options)

I use the `"progress"` option to check the collision in every movement cycle of the ship.

```js
console.clear();
$('document').ready(function() {

  var collided = false;
  var collidedWith = null;
  var $ship = $('.ship');
  var $walls = $('.wall')
  
  var $totalHeight = $('.inner').height(); //of walls
  var $maxHeight = Math.ceil(Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) - (Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) * 30) / 100); //30% of total wall height

  $('.wall').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).height($maxHeight);
    $('.wall.four').css({
      'height': $wallGap
    });
  })

  var $wallGap = Math.ceil($totalHeight / 3) - $maxHeight;
  var $wallOneTop = 0;
  var $wallTwoTop = $maxHeight + $wallGap;
  var $wallThreeTop = ($maxHeight * 2) + ($wallGap * 2);
  var $wallFourTop = -$('.wall.four').height() - $wallGap;

  $('.wall.one').css({
    'top': $wallOneTop
  });
  $('.wall.two').css({
    'top': $wallTwoTop
  });
  $('.wall.three').css({
    'top': $wallThreeTop
  });
  $('.wall.four').css({
    'top': $wallFourTop
  });


  function moveWall(wallObj) {
    var $currentTop = wallObj.position().top;
    var $limitTop = $('.inner').height();

    if ($currentTop >= $limitTop) {
      var $rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * ($maxHeight - $wallGap + 1) + $wallGap);
      wallObj.height($rand);
      var $top = -(wallObj.height());
    } else {
      var $top = (wallObj.position().top) + 5;
    }
    //    var $collide = checkCollision(wallObj);
    wallObj.css({
      'top': $top
    });
    // return $collide;
  }

  var $wallTimer = setInterval(function() {
    $walls.each(function(i, obj) {
      moveWall($(this));
      if (collided) {
        clearInterval($wallTimer);
      }
    })
  }, 40);


  function checkCollision() {
    var $shipWidth = $ship.width();
    var $shipHeight = $ship.height();
    var $shipLeft = $ship.position().left;
    var $shipRight = $shipLeft + $shipWidth;
    var $shipTop = $ship.position().top;
    var $shipBottom = $shipTop + $shipHeight;
    
    $('.wall').each(function(i) {

      var $wall = $(this);
      var $wallWidth = $wall.width();
      var $wallHeight = $wall.height();
      var $wallLeft = $wall.position().left;
      var $wallRight = $wallLeft + $wallWidth;
      var $wallTop = $wall.position().top;
      var $wallBottom = $wallTop + $wallHeight;

      if (
        $shipLeft < $wallRight &&
        $shipRight > $wallLeft &&
        $shipTop < $wallBottom &&
        $shipBottom > $wallTop
      ) {
        console.log("dhumm!");
        collided = true;
        collidedWith = $wall
        $wall.addClass('crashed')
        $ship.addClass('crashed')
        $ship.stop();
        return false;
      }
    })
  }







  $('.outer .inner').click(function() {
    var $ship;
    $ship = $('.ship');
    $shipLeft = $ship.position().left;
    $shipRight = $shipLeft + $ship.width();

    $inner = $('.inner');
    $innerLeft = $inner.position().left;
    $innerRight = $innerLeft + $inner.width();


    if (($shipLeft < $inner.width() - $ship.width())) {
      $ship.animate({
        "left": $inner.width() - $ship.width()
      }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "easing": "linear",
        "progress": checkCollision,
      });
    } else if (($shipRight >= $inner.width())) {
      $ship.animate({
        "left": '0'
      }, {
        "duration": 500,
        "easing": "linear",
        "progress": checkCollision,
      });
    }

  });


});
```

```css
.outer {
  background: #fff;
  border: 20px solid #efefef;
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer .inner {
  background: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.outer .inner .wall {
  width: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: #000;
}
.outer .inner .wall.crashed {
  background: red;
}


.outer .inner .ship {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.outer .inner .ship.crashed {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="wall one"></div>
    <div class="wall two"></div>
    <div class="wall three"></div>
    <div class="wall four"></div>

    <div class="ship"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a recommendation how I would do this from scratch.

Use an update cycle that is called by either `setInterval` or `setTimeout`, or even better with `requestAnimationFrame`. The updatecycle would be responsible for the time progress and orchestrate the different objects. The structure would be like this.

```
jQuery(function($) { // same as $('document').ready()
  var ship = ...;
  var boundaries = ...;
  var walls = ...;
  var clickEvents = [];

  document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {clickEvents.push(e)})
  var handleEvents = function() {}
  var setupWalls = function () {}
  var setupShip= function () {}
  var moveWalls = function () {}
  var moveShip = function () {}
  var checkCollision() {}

  var setup = function() {
    setupWalls();
    setupShip();
    // set the initial positions of the ships and the walls
  }

  var update = function() {
     handleEvents();
     moveWalls();
     moveShips();
     var collided = checkCollision();
     if (!collided) {
         setTimeout(update, 30);
     }
  }
  setup();
  update();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll try both of the approaches. :D